# How to click show more button while scraping from multiple pages?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a script that scrapes from 10 multiple pages at once.

```
#hyperlink_list is the list of the pages
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
for i in range(0,10):
    url = hyperlink_list[i]
    sleep(randint(10, 24))
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

Now from the pages, I am extracting this part:

[image]

In only some pages, there is the `show more` link where the description is longer. I want to click this link, and extract the description whenever the `show more` link is available.

Code for `show more` link:

```
<a id="rfq-info-header-description-showmorebutton">
              show more
            </a>
```

I want to click this link only if it's available, otherwise it will show element not found error.

Comment: Providing an url would not hurt - So everybody could reproduce, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `more = driver.find_element_by_id("rfq-info-header-description-showmorebutton")` (assuming the more link can *always* be found using this id). If the more button is not found, this will throw an exception. (see [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-id) for details)

Answer (score 1):

You should `try-except` block and we should look for `show more web element`. Below I am using `find_elements (plural)` and `len()` to get the size, if `>0` then web element must be present and then trying to click on it using Explicit waits.

If size is not `>0` then show more should not be visible and I am just printing a simple print statement in that block.

**Code :**

```
try:
    if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='rfq-info-header-description-showmorebutton']")) >0 :
        print("Show more link is available so Selenium bot will click on it.")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='rfq-info-header-description-showmorebutton']"))).click()
        print('Clicked on show more link')
    else:
        print("Show more link is not available")
except:
    print('Something else went wrong.')
    pass
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```